# How to find the number of times in which the symbol is duplicated in a string Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

How to find the number of times in which the symbol is duplicated in a string?

```
def duplicate_count(text)
  t = text.downcase
  t...
end

Test.assert_equals(duplicate_count("abc"), 0)
Test.assert_equals(duplicate_count("abcdeaa"), 1)
Test.assert_equals(duplicate_count("abcdeaB"), 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, it ain't pretty but works:

```
def duplicates string
  string.downcase.split('')
                 .group_by { |i| i }
                 .to_a
                 .select { |i| i[1].size > 1 }
                 .size
end

duplicates "abc"     #=> 0
duplicates "abcdeaa" #=> 1
duplicates "abcdeaB" #=> 2
```

A slightly better implementation:

```
def duplicates string
  string.downcase.split('')
                 .group_by { |i| i }
                 .values
                 .select { |i| i.size > 1 }
                 .size
end
```

Comment: @KirillZhuravlov updated answer with a better version:)

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_dups(str)
  str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|c,h| h[c.downcase] += 1}.count {|_,v| v >= 2}
end

count_dups "abc"      #=> 0
count_dups "abcdeaa"  #=> 1
count_dups "abcdeaB"  #=> 2
```

`Hash.new(0)` is often called a *counting hash*. See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), particularly in reference to the default value (here `0`).

Answer (score 0):

Based on @sagarpandya82 answer

```
def duplicate_count(text)
  text.downcase.chars.group_by(&:to_s).count { |v| v[1].count > 1 }
end
```

Comment: Consider `text.downcase.each_char.group_by(&:itself).count { |_,v| v.count > 1 }`. [String.each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) returns an enumerator, avoiding the need for the temporary array returned by `chars`. [Object#itself](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself) is more expressive than `to_s`, but has only been with us since v2.2. I personally prefer `group_by { |s| s }` to `group_by(&:to_s)`, which I find a bit too cute.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dupe_count(text, data)
  text.scan(data).count
end
dupe_count("abcc", "c") #<= 2
dupe_count("test", "t") #<= 2
dupe_count("lost", "w") #<= 0
```

Basically you have the text given as an argument, along with what you're trying to count within the text, you then scan the text for the given `data` you want to find and return a number with `count`